# How to open the browser when a link is pressed?

Tags: react-native-render-html

I am using version 4.2.2 of `react-native-render-html`. Given the following snippet:

```js
# App.js
import React from 'react';
import HTML from 'react-native-render-html';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <HTML html='<a href="https://duckduckgo.com/">A Link To Press</a>' />
    );
}
```

I would expect the web-browser to open when I press a link, but instead, nothing happens.

Comment: I believe you have to implement `onLinkPress`. Demo on their github: https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html/blob/40293bad8013a3a91f86c04da07f80f94fe15be6/Demo/src/HTMLDemo.js#L14

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**NB**: I've updated my answer to include differences between versions

### Important note

Because `Linkin.canOpenUrl` [has started requiring changing the android Manifest](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#canopenurl), [there has been a bug](https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-render-html/issues/546) preventing link press to open a browser in Android. This was **fixed in version 6.3.4**. So make sure to check your version!

### 6.x

Default behavior is to handle link press events with React Native `Linking` API. If you need to customize link press handling, you should use `renderersProps.a.onPress` prop.

```js
import React from 'react';
import RenderHTML from 'react-native-render-html';
import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';

const renderersProps = {
  a: {
    onPress(event, url, htmlAttribs, target) {
      // Do stuff
    }
  }
}

export default function App() {
    const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
    return (
        <RenderHTML
            contentWidth={width}
            source={{ html: '<a href="https://duckduckgo.com/">A Link To Press</a>' }}
            renderersProps={renderersProps}
        />
    );
}
```

### 5.x & 4.x

In v5, pressing links is handled by `Linking` API by default, and the behavior can be overridden by `onLinkPress` prop. On v4, it is your responsibility to handle links. For that end, use `onLinkPress`
prop and `Linking` utility from React Native. Be careful, if you're using Expo, you should import `Linking` from `expo-linking`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import HTML from 'react-native-render-html';
import { Linking } from 'react-native';
// import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';

function openLink(event, url) {
    Linking.openURL(url);
}

export default function App() {
    return (
        <HTML
            html='<a href="https://duckduckgo.com/">A Link To Press</a>'
            onLinkPress={openLink}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: In 6.x example should be import RenderHtml from 'react-native-render-html'; < RenderHtml contentWidth={width} source={{html: '<a href="https://duckduckgo.com/">A Link To Press</a>'}}  renderersProps={renderersProps} />